# SonarLint: Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "true"

Tags: java, android

I want to change this condition if (response != null) to not always evaluate true.what changes should i make in the code to achieve this?
added full code below

```
        if (ingenicoReaderDirect != null) {
            securityLog.logPerformance(LogPerformanceState.CardReaderState.CardAuthenticationStart, "");
            byte[] response = ingenicoReaderDirect.desfireExecuteCommand(data);
            securityLog.logPerformance(LogPerformanceState.CardReaderState.CardAuthenticationEnd, "");

            securityLog.logInfo(LogInfoEvent.GENERAL_INFO, "Card Auth Resp : " + String.format("%02X ", response[5]) + " " + String.format("%02X ", response[6]));

            // Check for positive response 90 00
            if (response != null) {
                securityLog.logInfo(LogInfoEvent.GENERAL_INFO, "Card Auth Resp : " + String.format("%02X ", response[5]) + " " + String.format("%02X ", response[6]));
                if (response[5] == (byte) 0x90 && response[6] == (byte) 0x00) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    securityLog.logWarning(LogWarningEvent.PROCESS_CARD_EXCEPTION, "Process Card Exception: Auth Failed");
                    PollingLooperThread.isCardAuthenticateFailed = true;
                    securityLog.logInfo(LogInfoEvent.GENERAL_INFO, "Card Auth Req: "
                            + print(SAMManager.requestDataForLogging) + ", Resp: " + print(response));
                }
            } else {
                securityLog.logInfo(LogInfoEvent.GENERAL_INFO, "Card Auth Req: "
                        + print(SAMManager.requestDataForLogging) + ", Resp: NULL");
            }

        }

        // Update transaction 18 if authentication failed
        deviceEventDataCounter.updateTransactionDataCounter(DeviceEventConstants.AC_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED, 0);
        return false;
    }
```

[image]

[compliant code for this code shown by sonarlint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLDji.png)

I tried many solution available on google but still unable to resolve.

Comment: Whats in `response[5]` & `response[6]`? They must always be the same if it is returning true

Comment: @Blundell added code where response was created

Comment: If i understand you correctly you could try: `if (response != null && response.length != 0) {`

Comment: @Blundell I tried this but issue still their.I also added some compliant and non compliant code this may help to understand the problem.

Comment: Dan Titiu has beat me to it :-)

Comment: @Blundell yeah bro thanks:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case `response` was null the line containing `response[5]` and `response[6]` would throw NullPointerException which means the `if (response != null)` will not be reachable when `response` is null.

If you remove or rewrite the line

`securityLog.logInfo(LogInfoEvent.GENERAL_INFO, "Card Auth Resp : " + String.format("%02X ", response[5]) + " " + String.format("%02X ", response[6]));`

to check for null response, then the if condition would not be redundant anymore.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Titiu  it worked by removing this line securityLog.logInfo(LogInfoEvent.GENERAL_INFO, "Card Auth Resp : " + String.format("%02X ", response[5]) + " " + String.format("%02X ", response[6])); .first i tried to paste it inside if (response != null)  this also solves the problem  but this code of line were already their so i removed it.